# CNAME record is not working while using cloudflare

Tags: dns, opendns, cname, cloudflare

Let's say I have a domain `test1.com` and `test2.com`. I have added the CNAME record as follows:

```
test1.com CNAME test2.com
```

While browsing the domain name `test1.com` it shows the sites of domain `test2.com` and working fine without any error.

But when I enable Cloudflare on `test2.com`, the `test1.com` do not work because it can't find the A records, IP of `test2.com`.

I want to use Cloudflare DNS and want to use the CNAME record as well, to browse the site of `test2.com` in `test1.com`.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not certain, but it seems like you need to be using OpenDNS (since you tagged your question with that service) for `test1.com` and Cloudflare DNS for `test2.com`. The other option would be to put both domains under Cloudflare DNS and use the CNAME features available for that service. Otherwise, please clarify how you have your DNS set up currently.